# Can I do normal logs in Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, logging, analytics, crashlytics

If I want to send logs in Firebase Crashlytics, can I do that? For example, I have a fragment and whenever someone goes to that screen, I want to send a log/indicator that this person went to this screen. I just want to see how many people went to the screen. Usually, logs in Crashltyics can be seen when there is a crash but for this case, it is not crashing the app.

Thank you

Comment: yes you can, put in a bundle and pass it along with the event in firebase analytics

Comment: just a note of warning, its a pain to view event values without stackdriver

Comment: Thank you and I will try this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you read the Firebase Analytics you can see how to send a log in Firebase without Crash. Actually it's a different way and different product in Firebase.

If you want you can read the tutorial article in the below https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android

Or you can follow these steps

1. add in gradlle

   `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:${latestversion}'`
2. Declare the FirebaseAnalytics object at top of your activity

   Kotlin -> `private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics`

   Java -> `private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;`

3.Initialize it in the onCreate()

Kotlin -> `firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)`

Java -> `mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);`

4. The following example demonstrates how to log a SELECT_CONTENT event:()

Kotlin ->

```
val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id)
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image")
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle)
```

Java ->

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this in a bit

Comment: BTW you can use the this code same time for crashlytics
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=2&platform=android
Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, "tag", "message");

Answer (score 1):

For this, you dont need to use Crashlytics, instead, use Firebase Events

Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android

You can also combine, Firebase Events with [Funnels](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317523?hl=en)

Comment: Great info, I will check them out. Thank you so much.